# How to convert static web site to ASP.NET Web Pages ("Razor") site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-webpages

I'd like to convert my static website to ASP.NET Web Pages ("Razor") site in Visual Studio 2013. The obvious step is to rename my `*.html` files to `*.cshtml` and add the dynamic logic. However, I've got a few more questions:

- Is `web.config` required or can I get away without it? If it's required, what's the minimal contents of it?
- Do I need to install Web Pages NuGet package? Visual Studio supposedly has Web Pages "included" but I'm not sure what that means for deployment (which will be Azure Web Sites).

I'm asking because I've tried to install the NuGet package but when I run the site, it says "Could not determine which version of ASP.NET Web Pages to use" even though the NuGet package had every chance to update the web.config appropriately. So maybe there's more to the conversion process but I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'm not sure which version of ASP.NET Web Pages you are using, but in your website there should be a Web.config file at the root. In here add the following config.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
</appSettings>
```

In the event that you already find a `<appSettings>` section please only include `<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />` within the existing `<appSettings>` section.

This should fix the problem. If you do not know which version of the ASP.NET Web Pages assemblies you are using, you can check the Packages.config file that was added when you used nuget to add ASP.NET Web Pages to your website.

Hope this helps!

----OLDER ANSWER: NOT RELEVANT TO OP----

What is your familiarity level with ASP.NET MVC? The proper terminology would be How to convert my static web site to a ASP.NET MVC Website. There are multiple versions of the ASP.NET MVC framework with version 5 being the latest. Unlike earlier Microsoft Web Forms framework, ASP.NET MVC relies more on convention over configuration.

MVC heavily relies on the common agreement of a convention such as folders being structured in a particular format. For example,

- Controller classes must be named with a suffix of “controller” such
  as MembershipController or AccountController.
- Controller classes should be placed in a folder called Controllers.
- Views and partial views should be placed in a folder following the convention of
  “Views/ControllerName” e.g. "Views/Membership".
- Your page layouts should be prefixed with an underscore “_”  character  and layout
  files are placed in the “Views/Shared” folder

Learning these conventions would give you a better understanding of what it takes to convert your website to a ASP.NET MVC website and identify whether that is the approach you want to take.

As far as your questions go.

- Yes you need to have a Web.config file. This file contains the Main configuration information for your website. When you create a new ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio, the project template usually creates a default Web.config file for you.
- As far as installing the nuget package is concerned, when you enable your web application for deployment to Azure in Visual Studio, the process sets the **Copy Local** property to true for any assemblies that are required for MVC and Silverlight Business Applications. This adds these assemblies to the service package that is used for deployment to Azure. More information on deploying a ASP.NET MVC website to Azure from Visual Studio is available [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420322.aspx)

Also I would suggest that you spend 15-20 minutes reading through the article at w3schools to help you get a better understanding of ASP.NET MVC Framework. [ASP.NET MVC Internet Application](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_app.asp) Hope this helps.

Comment: The application is meant to be "ASP.NET Web Pages", see http://www.asp.net/web-pages, not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Borek My bad! To understand further, are you using the Web Matrix IDE or are you using one of the Visual Studio IDEs? I'm trying to see if I can replicate the issue on my side to try and identify a solution.

Comment: It's in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: @Borek I've updated the answer. Can you please check if this works for you?